# ubuntu hotspot not detected by iPhone 4

Tags: iphone

i had window 7 installed on my HP G62 and i recently moved to ubuntu 11.10.

i used to share my internet connection to my iPhone using connectify since i only have wired connection in the student apartments.

i tried to set up a new hotspot using ubuntu, but the problem is that the iPhone is not even detecting that there is a hotspot.

is there anyway to fix this??

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

maybe its because of the encryption type.see what type is supported by ur iphone and use it
if you don’t know what is the supported type, try making the network without any password and if it worked u will know that you have to change the encryption type.

Comment: i tried making it without security, but even like this the iPhone as not able to detect it ..

Comment: can you tell me what exactly have you done to create the hotspot?

Comment: i went to System Settings - Network - Wireless - use as hotspot and then you can configure it ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a wifi scanner for iphone , then to see it's not a problem with your channels ! PLease do so then please let us know and please tell us if it's iphone 4s ? or iphone ? is it cracked?  can you see it with any other phone/ laptop?

Comment: it's an iPhone 4, and i used to connect it to the internet using connectify me in windows..

Comment: Can you see the hotspot with another phone or laptop?

Comment: i did not tried to do this ...